# Insert string before punctuation c

Tags: c

I'm looking to insert a HTML string tag into another string before the punctuation. 
i.e. Given "Robert:", I would like to output "**Robert**:"

Currently I have (apart of a function):

```
#define fhighlight     "<font_color="red"><b>"
#define bhighlight     "</b></font>"
#define punct          ".,;:!?"
#define wordlen        15
char w[wordlen];
w = "Robert:";
w = strcat(fhighlight,w);
if ((strchr(punct,w)==1) { /*check for punctuation in w*/
   /*not quite sure what to put here*/
} else {
  w = strcat(w,bhighlight);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code will break at many points. Debug and correct them.

Comment: The help you need is to read C language tutorials, take C classes, etc., because what you're writing is not C.

Comment: This program will not even compile, and when it does it will most likely crash. The crash we and the other problems we might help you with, but please read http://sscce.org/ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strchr() only looks for one character at a time (and you aren't calling it correctly), so would need to be called in a loop for each character in punct. Here is one function to look for any of them. Also, you are not using strcat() correctly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int char_position(const char *string,const char *chars)
{
   int length = strlen(string);
   while (*chars)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
         if ( string[i] == *chars )
         {
            return i;
         }
      }
      chars++;
   }
   return -1;
}

const char *highlight(const char *word)
{
#define fhighlight     "<font_color=\"red\"><b>"
#define bhighlight     "</b></font>"
#define punct          ".,;:!?"
#define wordlen        1500
   static char w[wordlen];  
   strcpy(w,fhighlight);
   int position = char_position(word,punct);
   if ( position != -1 )
   {
      strncat(w,word,position);
      strcat(w,bhighlight);
      strcat(w,&word[position]);
   } else {
      strcat(w,word);     
      strcat(w,bhighlight);
   }
   return w;
}


int main(void)
{
   printf("%s\n",highlight("Robert:"));
   printf("%s\n",highlight("Roberta"));
   printf("%s\n",highlight("LaDonna! is coming"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are having segmentation fault in your program.  Look at this fragment of your code:

```
char w[wordlen];
w = "Robert:";
w = strcat(fhighlight,w);
```

You are assigning w to a allocated space in the memory reserved for "Robert:" and then you are making a strcat with it, that indeed is also incorrect because you are making something like:

```
w = strcat("<font_color="red"><b>",w);
```

That will throw a segmentation fault.  I suggest you to re-start fresh.  Write your program again and use your memory properly.